# Defining the data in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use the data stored in the array `cottageGallery` from this mapped data?

```
const galleryData = components.map(g => {
   return {
      cottageGallery: g.cottageGallery,
      destinationGallery: g.destinationGallery,
      activitiesGallery: g.activitiesGallery,
   }
})
```

I thought it would simply be `const cottageGallery = galleryData.cottageGallery` but this returns undefined.

Comment: What's the purpose of that `map`? To create new objects with only a subset of the properties on the objects in `components`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, `galleryData` is going to be an array not an object as you are using javascript's [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. If you wanted to get the first item of the array you could do the following - `[0]` being the first item of the array.

```
const cottageGallery = galleryData[0].cottageGallery;
```

To log each `cottageGallery` you could use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and do the following:

```
galleryData.forEach(item => {
 console.log(item.cottageGallery);
})
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. This works fantastically. I'll accept it in a few minutes as it allows.

Answer (score 0):

`galleryData` is an **array** of the objects returned by the `map` callback. So you'd use `galleryData[index].cottageGallery`, where `index` is in the range `0` through `galleryData.length - 1` (or any of the various ways you access entries in an array, such as `for-of` or `forEach` or...[more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)).

Comment: Thank you. I've gone with Paul Fitzgeralds answer as it was first seen but I appreciate your help. That link is also very informative. Cheers

Comment: @Darren - Totally up to you. Not sure what you mean about "first seen," but this was *posted* first. But the important thing isn't timing, it's which answer you found most helpful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

`map` Will return an array so you won't be able to simply access `galleryData.cottageGallery`. You might want to use `.reduce()` on your array so the outcome can be the object your were trying to create

Answer (score 0):

You can also use forEach to access object array like below:

```
galleryData.forEach(a => {
 console.log(a.cottageGallery);
})
```